# C++ SFML 1.6 Sprite Position with Mouse

Tags: c++, button, input, mouse, sfml

When using SFML 1.6, I have run into a small problem, that I know there is an easy solution, but I currently cannot think of it/ haven't been able to find the answer via research.

I know that I have to transform the sprite to a global position using TransformToGlobal(someVector), but I don't know where to put it.

Here is an example of my code that I am using which does not work because it isn't in the global position.

```
if(sprite.GetSubRect().Contains(mouseX, mouseY))
    sprite.SetImage(someImage);
else
    sprite.SetImage(someOtherImage);
```

I tried adding sprite.TransformToGlobal(sprite.GetPosition()); before it, but it did not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the transformed mouse position and then checking if the sprites contains the mouse:

```
sf::Vector2f mousePos = App.ConvertCoords(App.GetInput().GetMouseX(), App.GetInput().GetMouseY());

if(sprite.GetSubRect().Contains(mousePos.x, mousePos.y))
    sprite.SetImage(someImage);
else
    sprite.SetImage(someOtherImage);
```